# develop email tracking plugin for outlook in c#

Tags: c#, plugins, outlook-addin

i want to develop email tracking plugin for outlook in c# , i am able to create the plugin but no idea how to track the email which is send from my outlook using c# ,please share any references blog or code.
 i have created simple hello world plugin for outlook

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;


namespace MyAddin
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private Office.CommandBar _objMenuBar;
    private Office.CommandBarPopup _objNewMenuBar;
    //private Outlook.Inspector Inspectors;
    private Office.CommandBarButton _objButton;
    private string menuTag = "MyMenu";
    Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyMenuBar();
        //Inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector +=
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (mailItem != null)
        {
            if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
            {
                mailItem.Subject = "This text was added by using code";
                mailItem.Body = "This text was added by using code";
            }

        }
    }

    private void MyMenuBar()
    {
        this.ErsMyMenuBar();

        try
        {
            _objMenuBar = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar;
            _objNewMenuBar = (Office.CommandBarPopup)
                             _objMenuBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup
                                                    , missing
                                                    , missing
                                                    , missing
                                                    , false);

            if (_objNewMenuBar != null)
            {
                _objNewMenuBar.Caption = "my Plugin";
                _objNewMenuBar.Tag = menuTag;
                _objButton = (Office.CommandBarButton)_objNewMenuBar.Controls.
                Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing,
                    missing, 1, true);
                _objButton.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.
                    msoButtonIconAndCaption;
                _objButton.Caption = "my Plugin";
                //Icon 
                _objButton.FaceId = 500;
                _objButton.Tag = "ItemTag";
                //EventHandler
                _objButton.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(_objButton_Click);
                _objNewMenuBar.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString()
                                               , "Error Message");
        }

    }


    #region VSTO generated code
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
    #endregion

    #region "Event Handler"
    #region "Menu Button"

    private void _objButton_Click(Office.CommandBarButton ctrl, ref bool cancel)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region "Remove Existing"

    private void ErsMyMenuBar()
    {
        // If the menu already exists, remove it.
        try
        {
            Office.CommandBarPopup _objIsMenueExist = (Office.CommandBarPopup)
                this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.
                FindControl(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup
                          , missing
                          , menuTag
                          , true
                          , true);

            if (_objIsMenueExist != null)
            {
                _objIsMenueExist.Delete(true);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message");
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I see that you used command bars in the code. Starting from Office 2007 the new UI is used. Command bars were deprecated since Office 2010. You need to use the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) instead. You can read more about the new UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

There are different ways for tracking emails:

1. Add a custom property. It is not the best way because the property can be vanished.
2. Use the Conversation*-like (*Id + *Index) properties of Outlook items. Outlook uses these properties to group related items in conversations.
3. Add your ID to the Subject line explicitly.

It is up to you which way is to choose...

Comment: can you please tell that how i can track that email is opened or not. i am able to get the plugin.

Comment: Have you tried to handle the [NewInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867841(v=office.15).aspx) and [Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865363(v=office.15).aspx) events?